# How to set DataGridView one column width to fill full width?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one DataGridView that have 3 column as name is A B and C, Column A and Column C width should be fix(like 200) but column B width should be fill to full DataGridView Width, It should set depend screen size.

I have create One Function that create column on DatagridView

```
 public void GenerateColumns(DataGridView dgv, string headerName, string headerText, int Minwidth, int FillWidth, DataGridViewColumnSortMode shortmode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable, bool Visible = true)
    {
        dgv.Columns.Add(headerName, headerText);
        dgv.Columns[headerName].MinimumWidth = Minwidth;

        dgv.Columns[headerName].Width = FillWidth;

        dgv.Columns[headerName].SortMode = shortmode;
        dgv.Columns[headerName].Visible = Visible;
    }
```

I have crate column at runtime

```
GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.SRNo, "SRNo", 50, 50, DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic, false);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.FYearID, "FYearID", 50, 50, DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic, false);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.Date, "Date", 50, 100);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.Particulars, "Particulars", 50, 500);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.VchType, "VchType", 50, 120);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.VchNo, "VchNo", 50, 80);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.AmountDebit, "Debit", 50, 150);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.AmountCredit, "Credit", 50, 150);
        GenerateColumns(dgvLedger, DbConst.DiscriptionApplicable, DbConst.Discription, 50, 50, DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable, false);
```

As Comment i have set AutosizeMode to Particulats Column but it not working

```
dgvLedger.Columns[DbConst.Particulars].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

[Image of DatagridView that view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeMzC.png)

Comment: Set the column's AutoSizeMode to Fill.

Comment: if i set AutoSizeMode to Fill then all column width size set to same, I want to set 200 width to Column A and Column C and between A and C Column B should set Fill.

Comment: Only Column B would be set to Fill.  The other columns would keep the AutoSizeMode to NotSet and a Width of 200.

Comment: Sir DataGridView column and Row bind from dataTable, I have set dgv.DataSource= Datatable . So during Design Mode i not able to set Column B to AutoSizeMode to fill

Comment: `dgv.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;`

Comment: I have update my post please refer it .

Comment: Code works for me as posted.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of "Column B" just setup AutoSizeMode(Layout section) to Fill.

Comment: Sir DataGridView column and Row bind from dataTable, I have set dgv.DataSource= Datatable . So during Design Mode i not able to set Column B to AutoSizeMode to fill